# Show div when is equal to parent div

Tags: jquery

I got a question about how to `show/hide` **div** just when it is equal to his parent div..

**For example:** I got a main `id="story-1"` and for this I got a fixed `id="footer-1"` and I want to show the **footer** when it is on the **story** height and end with the `bottom offset` like a `height` of the **story div**..

I tried this but it doesn't work.. I need help to fix this. Should I use the `scroll function` or just set a `var for story height` and set it up to equal..

```js
$('#footer-1').each(function(){
        var win = $('#story-1').height();
        if ($(this) === win) {
            $(this).slideUp();
        }
        else {
            $(this).slideDown();
        }
    });
```

**DEMO :** **http://jsfiddle.net/oesqpr7w/**

Comment: id must be unique so  $('#footer-1').each is totally wrong ..better to make a[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Why would a jQuery object ever be the same type as a number?

Comment: yeah, u are right.. @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: @SterlingArcher.. what u mean "same type as a number" ?

Comment: $(this) is an object and win is a number, you can't compare them

Comment: @LiborZahrádka look closely. `win` is set to `#story-1`'s height. That's a number value. `$(this)` is a jQuery object. They will never be equal. Did you want `$(this).height()`?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot or HTML?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Wait . . . I had something for this.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Ok, gotcha, but i dont wanna compare two numbers, i just want to show `footer` when is equal to height of `strory`.. like if i got 1300px height the story window and then i got another story for example `story-2` i just want the footer be shown for story 2..

Comment: Ok i make a simple demo..